# MySQL remote: Alter privilege granted, but not working

Tags: mysql, remote-access, alter-table

I'm trying to grant the ALTER TABLE privilege to a remote MySQL user, but when I execute the query it breaks with error: "ALTER command denied to user 'remotetest'@'*********' for table 'RemoteTest'"

Before the ALTER the table is created with CREATE TABLE in the very same script and this is succesful.

The user "remotetest" is granted the alter_priv in the mysql user table.

Privileges granted are:

```
mysql> select insert_priv, create_priv, alter_priv from user where user="**********";
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| insert_priv | create_priv | alter_priv |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Y           | Y           | Y          |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Anybody has a clue what's wrong?
The connection is clearly established and the user is able to create and show tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ALTER privilege enables use of `ALTER TABLE` to change the structure of tables. `ALTER TABLE` also requires the `CREATE` and `INSERT` privileges. Renaming a table requires `ALTER` and `DROP` on the old table, `ALTER`, `CREATE`, and `INSERT` on the new table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried setting all those rights and it still invokes the error. Please see updated thread description.

Comment: I found out the privileges weren't flushed. However, I marked your question as correct as it may help others in the same situation. You can add a remark that privileges need to be flushed : ) Thanks!